Applying for Schengen visa in India while doing PhD in US
I need help in applying for Schengen Visa for Germany/Switzerland. I am an Indian national pursuing my PhD in the US in New York. I want to attend a conference in Germany where I am invited to present my work. I want to ask if I can successfully apply for the Schengen visa in India. My reason for applying in India is that, since I received the invitation to give a talk at this conference, I am unable to find an appointment time in either of the consulates in New York before the 20th of June. And I have a pre-planned trip to India from July 3-Aug 5 to visit my family for one month, and I hope to fly to Europe directly from India. Further, I am required to attend a summer school in Michigan from 17th June - 30th June. Hence, dates in late June also would not work for me even if I were to postpone my trip to India. I have to be in India by July 23rd for a family reason. I have seen on this link:
https://eeas.europa.eu/archives/delegations/india/more_info/faq/schengen_visa_en.htm#faq2
under "Who can apply for Schengen visa in India?" that Indian nationals and nationals of other countries legally residing in India can apply. Persons residing in other countries may only apply if they can present a justification for applying in India rather than their country of residence.
Upon asking some other folks who are Indian nationals who reside in the US, who also tried to apply for Schengen visa in India, they were told that they have to reside in India for three months before applying.
A few more details about me, I have an Indian passport with my permanent residence in India. I also have a PAN card, Aadhar card and Domicile certificate which reflect my permanent residence in India. I am not sure if I am considered to be residing in India.
Since I am residing in the United States, there is the possibility I may only apply if I can present a justification. Can you please let me know what documents you think I may need to justify my application in this case?

What did VFS say when you contacted them?

I emailed VFS and they asked me to confirm with the embassy if I can apply, and they said that I may need to reside in India for six months before applying. I sent an email to the embassy. I think I am going to hear back tomorrow, as it is Sunday.

The hassle and nonsense of dealing with Schengen visas is why after 17 years I finally obtained American citizenship and passport.

@AugustineofHippo they hit the 2028 implementation target for the online application system

You don’t need to provide any documentation  the website that you are quoting here says this too

Indian nationals and nationals of other countries legally residing in India can apply.

Here is the source of common information from VFS and it says the same as above
https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/common-information
If you are an Indian national then you could apply from India
Your nationality takes over everything else!
You must apply through VFS and you need these documents in case of Germany short term visa vfs

The website the OP quotes is flagged archived 27/10/2016, confirmation from an up-to-date source would be advisable rather than relying on what could be obsolete information.

I checked the latest version it’s still the same

Thank you very much! I am just worried because some persons say they have applied in such a situation, and were told that they have to reside in India for the past six months to be able to apply. Do you have any suggestions on how I can confirm if I am eligible to apply? I am planning to call the embassy tomorrow. Do you have any suggestions on how I should present my situation?

You should call the embassy they will be able to answer your questions

The sentence could be read differently, namely that both citizens and non-citizens can apply provided they are legally resident (which is the main rule in the Schengen visa code).

@Relaxed you are a legal resident in your home country by virtue of holding citizenship. That should suffice when applying for the visa in India

@SaranshSharma No, you are not. Those are two distinct concepts.
